# Template specialization of templated type not selected when using multiple typenames

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say I have

```
template <typename T>
class F;
```

I can create another template who takes an `F` as a type, with a default and a specialization.

```
template <typename S>
class G;

template <>
template <typename T>
class G <F<T> >
{
};
```

I can instantiate `G<F<int> > g_of_f`. The compiler correctly selects the specialization of `G`, and everything is great.

So here's my problem. I want to do this with more than one template typename in the list. But when I try

```
template <typename U, typename S>
class H;

template <typename U>
template <typename T>
class H <U, F<T> >
{
};
```

now I cannot instantiate `H<void, F<int> > h_of_f`, because the compiler is selecting the original template `H` and not the specialization.

I've observed the same behavior with g++ 4.1 and g++ 4.4.

What is the difference between `G` and `H` that's preventing the compiler from working the way I'm expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `template<>` syntax is used to introduce an *explicit* specialization declaration, what you have here are *partial* specializations :

```
template <typename S>
class G;

template <typename S>
class G < F<S> >
{
};

template <typename U, typename S>
class H;

template <typename U, typename S>
class H <U, F<S> >
{
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename U, typename S>
class H;

template <typename U, typename T>
class H <U, F<T> > {};
```

This syntax:

```
template <> template <typename U>
```

is for specializing/defining template members outside of template:
http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#outsidedef